# Sempre voltar ao topo da tela ao clicar em links de uma SPA com Angular.Js

Tags: angularjs

Tenho um projeto em angular, da qual com o `$routeProvider` defino minhas views e chamo as devidas controllers, e utilizo o `<ng-view></ng-view>` para apresenta-las em meu site.

São poucas páginas, porem são paginas com barra de rolagem, e ao clicar em um link que troco de uma view para outra `<a ng-href="/projeto/#/produto/{{produtoId}}>{{produtoNome}}</a>`.

Porém, quando passa para a próxima página, a rolagem está na mesma altura, ela não volta ao topo, sei que é por ser uma SPA, não está literalmente trocando de página. Mas existe alguma maneira fácil do angular, de sempre que trocar de rota, a rolagem da página voltar sempre ao topo?

Obrigado.

Comment: Acho que e isso o que procura https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio na verdade não, vou tentar montar um exemplo do meu caso e ja edito a pergunta.

Comment: Da uma olhada ai :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/27430246/3956218

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio caraca! é exatamente isso que eu queria! hahaha, olhei a teoria q isso deve fazer o q eu preciso! porem eu não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar hahaha, preciso de alguma dependência do angular para esse $rootScope.$on? vi que o autor da pergunta usa o angular-ui-route, eu uso apenas o angular-route. isso implica no evento $stateChangeSuccess? Obrigado :D

Comment: acho que usar location.href='#altura'; seria mais simples no seu caso, vou editar a resposta do Thiago usando, vê se funciona... não tem problema usar funções nativas de javascript dentro de um $scope angular, funciona do mesmo jeito :)

Comment: Se conseguir criar um exemplo minimo com o que tem, talvez de pra tentar te ajudar usando o exemplo do angular, você pode notar que ele usa javascript puro pra fazer a ancora do elemento

Comment: Poste somente o código de quando passa para a próxima página Aldo

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio eu navego entre as views com o `<a ng-href="/#/...rota">` com um link normal mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando somente o Angular, encontrei a [Documentação do ngView](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView), que recomenda usar:

```
<div class="ng-view" autoscroll="true"></div>
```

Mas se você quiser usar um pouco de jQuery faz o seguinte, adiciona a Função de Scroll a todos os `<a>` usando `.delegate()` assim o jQuery atibui mesmo aos `<a>` criados dinamicamente pelo AngularJS :

```js
$("body").delegate("a", "click", function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
});
```

```css
#altura {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="altura"></div>
<a>Todos os Links</a>
```

E se você quiser fazer usando somente JS puro:

```js
var Anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < Anchors.length ; i++) {
    Anchors[i].addEventListener("click", 
        function() {
            document.body.scrollTop = 0;
        }, 
        false);
}
```

```css
#altura {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<div id="altura"></div>
<a>Todos os Links</a>
```

Outra solução usando JS Puro:

```css
#altura {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<div id="altura"></div>
<a onclick="location.href='#altura'">Todos os Links</a>
```

Comment: Com isso você diz que com o Angular.js não há nenhum jeito de fazer isto mesmo? Eu pensei em fazer da mesma forma que você mostrou (mas sem usar o jquery pois não inclui a dependência dele no meu projeto, utilizando apenas javascript). Mas preferi perguntar para saber se há algum meio nativo do Angular que faria isso. Obrigado.

Comment: @AldoFernandesJunior Você não usa jQuery? Vou alterar então! Olha você quer somente com Angular e sem usar JS nativo, isso?

Comment: @ThiagoSantos tomei a liberdade de acrescentar meu exemplo na sua resposta, se não se importar

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio não me importo, mas ele teria que adicionar esse `onCLick` em todos os elementos, não sei se ele deseja isso

Comment: Você não entendeu rs, se ele colocar no código, não importa aonde `location.href='#altura'` ele vai pra ancora :) Por isso que eu acho que talvez fosse a melhor solução.

Comment: Dessa maneira que vocês falaram, eu teria que adicionar onclick mesmo pois, como uso angular, tenho alguns links que são carregados após a renderização da DOM, portanto os links não entrariam no addEventListener. Ou eu colocaria o jQuery para fazer da primeira maneira @.@

Comment: @AldoFernandesJunior o jQuery anterior não funcionaria com itens criados dinamicamente, mas o atual sim, fiz uma pequena edição.

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio removi tua sugestão pois não funcionaria com links criados dinamicamente, estou pensando se não removo também minha sugestão com JS.

Comment: Caraca Thiago santos! é uma coisa tão simples, esse autoscroll="true" funcionou exatamente para o que eu precisava! O.O, e olha que eu dei uma procurada D: acho que preciso melhorar minhas skills de google hahaha Muito obrigado pela ajuda! :D upvoted!

Comment: @AldoFernandesJunior Fico feliz em ajudar e, deixando uma dica, parece que search skill é uma coisa natural, mas não é, então sempre dá aquela forçadinha extra na pesquisa que tu vai melhorando sim. Um abraço!